# MySQL DATE type value gets displayed with hours/minits/seconds, however its is not stored like that in the database

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, date, visual-studio-2013, c++-cli

I have DATE type column in a MySQL database table with dates stored in it. I am using the YYYY-MM-DD format when I upload the dates to the database.

When I check the values they are stored in the correct and expected format (2005-01-02), however when I am attempting to read these values with my C++ program I am receiving something like this: 02/01/2005 00:00:00

I don't really understand the reason, I thought in the DATE type only the YYYYMMDD gets stored without the time. The other weird thing is the reformatting I thought YYYY-MM-DD is an accepted format.

Here is my code:

```
String^ getDateOfBirth = myReader->GetString("player_date_of_birth");
DateOfBirthLabel->Text = getDateOfBirth;
```

I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That's most probably just a quirk of string conversion, it just uses the default `DateTime` format. Why don't you use `GetDateTime` instead of `GetString`? You could provide your own format that way.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Thank you for your suggestion. The answer is probably obvious but I can't figure out what type of variable should I store the date in in my program, because GetDateTime is not supporting a String^ type.

Comment: `GetDateTime` returns a... `DateTime` :) If you want a `String^`, convert it like this: `myReader->GetDateTime("player_date_of_birth").ToString("d")`.

Comment: Thank you very much, i got it to work partly but now I can't show the variable's value in a Label I guess because it only accepts string? So I need to convert it but what "d" stands for in the code you suggested? How could I convert it to a format like YYYY-MM-DD?

Comment: Use `yyyy-MM-dd` instead of `d`. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx).

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Thank you very much, it is working properly now.